# PHP Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, classloader, require, require-once

I've a very strange issue. In one class "SMSNotifier" I have

```
require_once (__DIR__ . "/../InvitationNotifier.php");
[...] 
class SMSNotifier extends InvitationNotifier {
[...] 
}
```

this class is included in another script which is called from the cli. When calling this script I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'InvitationNotifier' not found in [...]/include/classi/notifiche/notifiers/SMSNotifier.php on line 12
```

The strange thing is that if I replace the require_once with a require I get instead

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class InvitationNotifier in [...]/include/classi/notifiche/InvitationNotifier.php on line 11
```

What could be the issue here?

Thank you in advance for any thought. I've ran out of them...

Comment: Is there an `InvitationNotifier` class in `InvitationNotifier.php`? Does it use a namespace?

Comment: Yes, there is and no it does not use a namespace.
abstract class InvitationNotifier implements Notifier {
}

Comment: What happens when you use the absolute path to the class?

Comment: Did you place any of your requires inside of a container like a function or a class? I don't know how this scenario would play out: Inside a function, you require_once InvitationNotifier. It is included and the function ends. Now, outside the function, you require_once it again. It was already required, but the class definition was contained inside the function, so it doesn't exists when you tried to use it. Changing to require will define the class in the function (one define) and outside it (a second define - error).

Comment: Well actually the require/require_once is outside the class definition and outside any function. I didn't understand your point, if you can elaborate a little

Answer (score 3):

I've continued trying to understand the issue and I've found out that there was a circular dependency. I've "cut it" down and the issue is gone. Hope this can help someone

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** just be loading up files like it's 1990.  Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (PHP) and follow PSR-4 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4

**composer.json**

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"InvitationNotifier\\": "lib/"}
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once('autoload.php');
```